# RegEx for matching a number greater than 9?

Tags: regex

How to put a number greater than 9 to regexp character set?

For example, I can do `^[01236]$`, but what if I want to put `100` as an option to the set?

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Regular expressions don't understand numeric values.  They only match patterns of characters.  If you want to test the numeric value of a string, use your host language.

Comment: @AndyLester yeah, you're right. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put a specific multi character strings you can use:

```
^(10|100|200|301|601)$
```

Which will match `10`, `100`, `200`, `301`, and `601`

test: https://regex101.com/r/bptbsx/1

Answer (score 2):

If a number is greater than 9, it is more than 2 digits and the first digit is not 0. So the regex you might want to use is: `^[1-9][0-9]+$`

Answer (score 2):

'\d+' can find number having 1 or more digits